# Create list of object members from object list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume I have a list of objects like so:

```
var list = [
    { date: '22/9/2016', status: 1, id: '11111' },
    { date: '23/9/2016', status: 1, id: '22222' },
    { date: '24/9/2016', status: 1, id: '33333' }
];
```

I would like to create a list of the ids of all the objects in the above list, so that I end up with:

```
var idList = ['11111', '22222', '33333'];
```

Obviously, I could iterate through the list and build the idList manually.
Is there an alternative way of doing this through either native JS, angularJS, or perhaps another library.

Manually iterating through the list isn't a big overhead, I just want to ensure I'm not ignoring functionality of JS / angularJS that would do this for me instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var list = [
    { date: '22/9/2016', status: 1, id: '11111' },
    { date: '23/9/2016', status: 1, id: '22222' },
    { date: '24/9/2016', status: 1, id: '33333' }
];
var idList = list.map(item => item.id );
console.log(idList);
```

Comment: take a look on this comparison https://ryanpcmcquen.org/javascript/2015/10/25/map-vs-foreach-vs-for.html

Comment: I knew there must have been a single line way of doing this instead of manually iterating. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var ids = list.map(function(item) { return item.id});
```

Should work.